# Poisson times Binomial distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

If I have two random variables: ***N*** follows Poisson distribution with mean as $\lambda$, and ***X*** follows binomial distribution with success rate of *p*, the output of ***N*** is the number of trials for ***X***, according to this link [A binomial multiplied by a poisson](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211914/a-binomial-multiplied-by-a-poisson/211928), ***XN*** should follow Poisson distribution with mean *$p\lambda$*

However, I was reading "Probability for Statistics and Machine Learning" for DasGupta and I found this example

[image]

I do not know how those two cases differ, but I think I am missing a fundamental point.

Comment: According to the post you linked, it is not $XN$, but rather $X$ that should be Poisson with parameter $p \lambda$, which makes sense : A Poisson process counts $\frac 1{\lambda}$ times a minute, and exactly $p$ proportion of these are counted . $XN$ is then the product of two Poissons, but they are not independent, so you need to condition on $N$ to get the expectation. (Note : This also means that the attached post does not have a satisfactory answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hierarchical model is not the same as the product of two random variables.

Here is a simple example of a product:  Let $$\Pr[X = x] = \theta^x (1-\theta)^{1-x}, \quad x \in \{0,1\}, \\ \Pr[Y = y] = p(1-p)^{y-1}, \quad y \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}.$$

So $X$ is Bernoulli with parameter $\theta$ and $Y$ is geometric with parameter $p$.  Now $XY$ is a new random variable:  clearly, $$\Pr[XY = 0] = \Pr[X = 0] = 1 - \theta,$$ since $\Pr[Y = 0] = 0$.  And for each positive integer $y$, $$\Pr[XY = y] = \theta p(1-p)^{y-1},$$ since $XY = y$ only if $X = 1$ and $Y = y$.

Now here is an example of a hierarchical model.  Let $$\Pr[N = n] = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}, \quad n \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}, \\ \Pr[X = x \mid N = n] = \binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x}, \quad x \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n\}.$$  Note that the second distribution is *conditional* on the first:  in other words, $N$ is Poisson with rate $\lambda$, but $X$ **given** $N = n$ is binomial with $n$ trials with success probability $p$.  The product of $N$ and $X$ is **not** the same random variable as the **marginal** (or unconditional) distribution $X$, which is $$\begin{align}
\Pr[X = x] &= \sum_{n=x}^\infty \Pr[X = x \mid N = n] \Pr[N = n] \\
&= \sum_{n=x}^\infty \binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} \\
&= \sum_{n=x}^\infty \frac{1}{x! (n-x)!} e^{-p\lambda} e^{-(1-p)\lambda} p^x (1-p)^{n-x} \lambda^x \lambda^{n-x} \\
&= e^{-p\lambda} \frac{(p\lambda)^x}{x!} \sum_{n=x}^\infty e^{-(1-p)\lambda} \frac{((1-p)\lambda)^{n-x}}{(n-x)!} \\
&= e^{-p \lambda} \frac{(p\lambda)^x}{x!}.
\end{align}$$ by the law of total probability.  Therefore, the unconditional distribution of $X$ is Poisson with rate $p\lambda$.  This would imply, for instance, $\Pr[X = 1] = p\lambda e^{-p\lambda}$.  However, as I have stated, $NX$ is not the same thing:  $$\begin{align}
\Pr[NX = 1] &= \Pr[(N = 1) \cap (X = 1)] \\
&= \lambda e^{-\lambda} p.
\end{align}$$

So when you write "$XN$ should follow a Poisson distribution with mean $p\lambda$," you are incorrect.  The question you linked to contains a similar misunderstanding, hence your confusion.  That question talks about multiplying two **probability mass functions**, not **random variables**.  And then the answer that is given assumes that this multiplication comes in the form of a hierarchical model, which is not necessarily true.

As for the question that you specifically posted, regarding the eggs, this is clearly a binomial-Poisson hierarchical model; i.e., $N$ gives the number of laid eggs, and $X \mid N$ gives the number of eggs that fertilized.  Then the covariance between $X$ and $N$ is calculated by the formula $$\operatorname{Cov}[X,N] = \operatorname{E}[XN] - \operatorname{E}[X]\operatorname{E}[N],$$ and in this formula, $XN$ truly means the product of the random variables $X$ and $N$.  And now, by the law of total expectation, we have $$\operatorname{E}[XN] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[XN \mid N]] = \operatorname{E}[N \operatorname{E}[X \mid N]] = \operatorname{E}[N (Np)] = p \operatorname{E}[N^2] = p (\lambda^2 + \lambda).$$

The first two equalities are simply conditioning on the outcome of $N$; i.e., it is a shorthand way to write $$\operatorname{E}[XN] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \operatorname{E}[nX \mid N = n]\Pr[N = n] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( n \operatorname{E}[X \mid N] \right)\Pr[N = n].$$  The third equality arises from the fact that, conditioned on $N$, $X \mid N$ is binomial and has expectation $Np$.  The fourth equality simply factors the constant parameter $p$ out of the expectation, leaving the final equality which is the second moment of a Poisson random variable.

Comment: you mentioned that multiplying pmfs is not the same as multiplying random variables, if I have random variables X, Y, and Z=XY. How to derive Z pmf?

Comment: @omar It is complicated for discrete valued variables in general.  For instance, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and identically distributed on $\{1, 2, \ldots \}$, then $\Pr[XY = 5] = \Pr[(X = 1) \cap (Y = 5)] + \Pr[(X = 5) \cap (Y = 1)]$ but $\Pr[XY = 6]$ has more ways to factor $6$; e.g., $(X,Y) \in \{(1,6), (2,3), (3,2), (6,1)\}$.

Comment: @AntoniParellada Thank you for the correction.

Comment: It's an excellent answer, thank you for retouching that line. NB, on my prior comment I meant to type $E(XN)=E(E(XN \vert N)) = E(E(nX \vert N=n))= E(n E(X \vert N=n))= E(n (np)\vert N=n)=pE(n^2\vert N=n)=pE(N^2).$

Answer (score 2):

The correct statement is the following

- $N\sim  Po (\lambda)$
- $X|N\sim Bin(N,p)$

Thus

- $X\sim  Po(\lambda p)$

**Proof:**

$$P(X,N)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^N}{N!}\binom{N}{x}p^x(1-p)^{N-x}$$

$$P(X=x)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x p^x}{N!}\sum_{N=x}^{\infty}\binom{N}{x}[\lambda(1-p)]^{N-x}$$

$$P(X=x)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}(\lambda p)^x}{x!}\sum_{N-x=0}^{\infty}\frac{[\lambda(1-p)]^{N-x}}{(N-x)!}= \frac{e^{-\lambda}(\lambda p)^x}{x!}e^{\lambda(1-p)}= \frac{e^{-\lambda p}(\lambda p)^x}{x!} $$

$x=0,1,2,...$